# Get the id of the ul where my li is placed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have now a full working Drag'n'Drop Script, but I still want to add a function that the script displays the `id` of the `<ul>` where my `<li>` is placed.

I tried a few solutions but none of them worked for me and I think it is because my script is dynamic and not static. All in the left div named `Teilnehmer` are some `<li>` and they can be dragged into the right div with different street names. After an `<li>` is dropped the `<li>` still remains in the left div, but it should display the `id` of the `<ul>` where the `<li>` is dropped in brackets, e.g. : `Jürgen W.(48)`

Does someone have a solution? Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf1vvjjb

Comment: Do you mean $(this).parents('ul') ?

Comment: I tried something similar to this but it didn´t work.Could you maybe try it on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#li_id').parent()[0]
```

Comment: I switched: <li id="node1">Peter Z.</li>  to -> <li id="node1">Peter Z.<script type="text/javascript">$('#li_id').parent()[0]</script></li> .- but it still doesn´t work , could you maybe take a look at the fiddle and maybe edit it like the way you thought, Greetz

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also best not to post an answer when you don't have a plausible reason to explain why your answer correctly addresses the OP's issue.

Comment: it will return the first parent which is ul in this case. And from that ul element we can get the id easily.

Comment: Could you maybe insert your suggestion into a fiddle , because the way I did it it won´t work. Thanks

Comment: Find the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf1vvjjb/1/). I have added piece of code in drag end event.